# PostgreSQL - How to display count = 0 on this query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

shelter_inventory (table)

```
gid | pav_type | yes
 1  |  1       | 1
 2  |  1       | 1
 3  |  0       | 1
 4  |  2       | 1 
 5  |  2       | 0
```

this is the current query (**does not display count = 0**)

```
SELECT pav_type, count(*) FROM shelter_inventory 
WHERE yes = 1 GROUP BY pav_type ORDER BY pav_type
```

and I want the result to display like this

```
pav_type | count(*)
 0       |  1
 1       |  2
 2       |  1 
 3       |  0
```

How could I query on this case? I use PostgreSQL.

Comment: Your example table does not have a pav_type of value 3 so it will never show up in the group by. Do you have a separate table that defines the pav_types?

Comment: your query looks good for me.. if u would have had the row for pav_type 3 in ur table you will have that

Comment: no, pav_type is simple like that (0,1,2,3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `pav_type` values are sequential, then you could use [`generate_series`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES) in place of an external table:

```
select p.pav_type, count(yes)
from generate_series(0,3) as p(pav_type)
left outer join shelter_inventory s
  on p.pav_type = s.pav_type and s.yes = 1
group by p.pav_type
order by p.pav_type
```

This yields:

```
 pav_type | count 
----------+-------
        0 |     1
        1 |     2
        2 |     1
        3 |     0
```

This:

```
generate_series(0,3) as p(pav_type)
```

essentially generates an inlined table with a single column called `pav_type` and four rows: 0, 1, 2, 3. And you need to have the `s.yes = 1` in the join condition (rather than the WHERE) because you want the `yes = 0` values to be in the pre-grouped result set; if `s.yes = 1` is in the WHERE clause then the `yes = 0` rows won't be counted regardless of what the join condition is.

If your `pav_types` do not nicely fit with `generate_series` (i.e. not sequential or step-sequential) and you only have a small number of them, you could join to a [VALUES expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-values.html):

```
select p.pav_type, count(yes)
from (values (0), (1), (2), (3)) as p(pav_type)
left outer join shelter_inventory s
  on p.pav_type = s.pav_type and s.yes = 1
group by p.pav_type
order by p.pav_type
```

You need to make sure you get all the parentheses in the right places of course.

If you do have the `pav_types` in a separate table then do a LEFT OUTER JOIN to that table instead of using the `generate_series`. If your `pav_types` are not sequential and you have too many to sensibly put in a VALUES expression, then build a table to hold the valid `pav_type` values and LEFT OUTER JOIN to that.

Comment: +1 I never knew about `generate_series()`! Thanks for posting :)

Comment: @Bohemian: I learned about `generate_series` the same way you just did :)

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate table with *all* pav_type values in it, let's name it pav_type_ref. Then outer join from it.

```
create table pav_type_ref (pav_type int);
insert into pav_type_ref values (1), (2), (3);

SELECT r.pav_type, sum(case when i.pav_type is null then 0 else 1 end)
FROM pav_type_ref r
left join shelter_inventory i on i.pav_type = r.pav_type
WHERE yes = 1
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUM(CASE WHEN yes=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`, you can also include `GROUP BY pav_type HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN yes=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0`